# creating new numpy array dataset for each loop

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create a new dataset variable everytime within a for loop 
using .append as below wont work. Note the shape of each numpy array type variable is (56, 25000)

```
ps=[1,2,3,4]

for subj in ps:

    datapath = '/home/subj%d' % (subj) 

    mydata.append = np.genfromtext(datapath, mydatafile)
```

so basically I need her 4 instances of mydata, each with a shape of (56, 25000), or that for each loop a new dataset variable is created eg mydata1, ..., mydata4....however .append won't do it. I could do this with

```
if ps==1: mydata1 = np.genfromtext(datapath, mydatafile)

if ps==2: mydata2 = np.genfromtext(datapath, mydatafile)
```

etc but I have far to many instances of ps, so would be nice to loop it

thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't assign to `append`. This does it `mydata.append(np.genfromtext(datapath, mydatafile))`?

Comment: You can either go with @jedwards answer or if you need numpy indexing, you can easily initialize an empty numpy array and fill it with each iteration. Get space:`data=numpy.empty(4,56,25000)`,and then in each loop `data[i-1]=np.genfromtext(datapath,mydatafile)`. Beware that you must know the length of datasets and number of datasets beforehand for this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without more code, but `.append` is generally a method, and should be called like this:

```
some_container.append(your_object)
```

Note I'm also initializing `mydata` to be an empty list -- you don't show how you initialize it (if you do at all), so just be aware:

```
mydata = []
for subj in [1,2,3,4]:

    datapath = '/home/subj%d' % (subj) 

    mydata.append( np.genfromtext(datapath, mydatafile) )
```

Then, `mydata` will be a 4-element Python list of numpy arrays.

There is also numpy's [`vstack()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) and [`concatenate()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) functions which may be worth looking in to.

Lastly, just wanted to point out that

```
ps = [1,2,3,4]
for sub in ps:
    ...
```

Can be written as (as I do above):

```
for sub in [1,2,3,4]:
    ...
```

but also as:

```
for sub in range(1,5):
    ...

# or

for sub in range(4):
    datapath = '/home/subj%d' % (subj + 1)
    ...
```

Comment: But don't put the numpy stack expressions inside the loop.  Collect a list and concatenate once.